# Image Dimensions without loading

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to get the width and height of an image on the disk without loading the whole image into memory.

I need to support BMP and PNG images; TGA would be nice too.

I am already using DirectX11, DirectX Tool Kit, CxImage and the Boost library, so a way to do it with one of these libraries would be great. However, I am also willing to use another library

Comment: Have you looked at this answer here? It seems to be something of the same context. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5354657/1484168

Comment: @stefan yes it was meant to be a comment. thanks for the conversion

Comment: thanks @iRebel_85, this helped with the implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For BMP, read in [bytes 18 through 21](http://www.fastgraph.com/help/bmp_header_format.html) to get the width, and bytes 22 though 25 to get the height.

For PNG, read in the dimensions from the file's [IHDR chunk](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html), which looks to start after the first eight bytes of the file, and the eight bytes of the [header of the IHDR chunk itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Structure.html). Bytes 16 through 19 would give the width, and bytes 20 through 23 give the height.

Likewise, for TGA, you could read the [first 18 bytes (with advised notes)](http://www.paulbourke.net/dataformats/tga/) into a TGA header `struct` and then dereference the struct instance's `width` and `height` properties.

Within C++, you can use standard C I/O (e.g., [`fopen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) [`fseek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) and [`fread()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/)) to open, move and read bytes from a file pointer. You wouldn't have to read in the entire file: just move to the correct byte offset and then read in the correct number of bytes.

Comment: I forgot to add the binary flag when opening the file. Corrected version is here http://pastebin.com/uR8T5wYf