# How to resize the main window to the dimensions of an image resource

Tags: qt

Earlier last week I created a window in Python that resized the main window to the dimensions of the background image. I wanted to do the same in QT. I've managed to figure out the syntax to resize the main window through its constructor.

```
this->setFixedSize(QSize(600, 600));
```

I'm curious how I might now set the width and height parameters to the same parameters of an image in the resource file. I was thinking something like this:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem image(QPixmap("url(:/images/background.png);"));
int x = image.width
int y = image.length
this->setFixedSize(QSize(x, y));
```

edit:

In summary, I want to resize the main window to the same dimensions of an image file which so the window wraps around the background image. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354459/c-how-to-get-the-image-size-of-a-png-file-in-directory) I have to parse the image header to read the dimensions... sounds too complicated. Is there a third party library?

Comment: Have you tried `resize()`?

Comment: No I haven't. I want to resize the main window to the same dimensions of an image file which so the window wraps around the background image. According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354459/c-how-to-get-the-image-size-of-a-png-file-in-directory) I have to parse the image header to read the dimensions... sounds too complicated. Is there a third party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `QGraphicsPixmapItem` use [`QImage`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html) to get the size of your image.

```
QImage image(":/images/background.png");
if(!image.isNull())
    setFixedSize(image.size());
else
    //loading the image failed, show some error message or something
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. What header do I have to import to use this library `QImage`?

Comment: @the_prole `#include <QImage>`. It is also mentioned in the docs of `QImage` I linked to in the answer.

Comment: Why do the headers in my `main.cpp` look different from the headers in the QT documentation e.g. `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"` vs. `#include <QImage>`? In any case, `QImage` is not recognized...

Comment: @the_prole Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162030/difference-between-angle-bracket-and-double-quotes-while-including-heade). What do you mean by not recognized?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to adjustSize , after setting to new ?

```
this->setFixedSize(QSize(x, y));
this->adjustSize();
```