# Dart - How to get the Image height and width of a png file?

Tags: dart

Is there a way in getting this sizes? Using command line. Thanks in advance. and can I ask something good tutorials in Dart?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a built-in feature that allows to do that except readying the content byte-wise and interpreting the values like explained for C++ in [C++ How to get the Image size of a png file (in directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354459/c-how-to-get-the-image-size-of-a-png-file-in-directory)

The [image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image) package seems to provide this functionality though. [decodePng](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/image/1.1.22/image/decodePng.html) returns an image that has a width and height property.

Answer (score 2):

The build-in function [`decodeImageFromList()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/decodeImageFromList.html) can help you with that. Its callback contains an `Image` that includes the width and height.